# Using the AVD in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I am getting a few errors when I try to run the AVD with a basic program and other solutions have not worked. These are the errors:

```
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: device fd:608
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument 
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

I tried changing the RAM size in the AVD to 512 MB as suggested by other posts, but that did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the RAM size on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

At run time, the computer simply cannot give the app the requested amount of RAM ( *Maybe you have opened applications that consume a large amount for ram i.e Firefox, or Internet explorer or some other desktop applications*). Lower the amount needed by stopping these processes.Hence,this issues arrived due to the fact that PC is not able to allocate that much RAM to the new Emulator.
Hopefully,you have already tried this

> Window -> Android SDK Manager ->Tools -> Manage AVDs
>
> And Select your Virtual Device and click edit button in the right
>   side.
>
> Select your device and click Edit button in right part of window

Then in Memory Options secton find RAM parameter and set it to *512* for example.

> Click OK and run your project.

If you are running with HAX ,then set the parameter to 768Mb.

After all this then **reboot your system**.....and i believe it should work...